# Eclipse "check for updates", "install new software" and "marketplace" not showing in help menu

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm using eclipse 4.19 on marjaro 21.0.7 on linux 5.12.9-1 and these three options are not showing up in the help menu. I have tried reinstalling eclipse, deleting /opt/eclipse , and uninstalling plugins, but none themes to work.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted ~/.eclipse and reinstalled again. After, I only installed software with the marketplace instead of the "install new software" and it resolved the issue